# Batch copy file name action in Apple Script for Automator Mac OS X

Tags: applescript, batch-processing, osx-mountain-lion, automator

Can one automate the process of copying a file name and pasting it in the Spotlight Comment box of that file? How does that Apple Script for OS X looks like?

I would need to do that a thousand times otherwise:

1. Hitting enter to select the file
2. Short cut typing Hotkey Cmd C
3. Short cut typing Hotkey Cmd I to open that info window
4. Hitting tab button twice to enter the Spotlight Comment box
5. Short cut typing Hotkey Cmd v
6. Short cut typing Hotkey Cmd w to close that info window

The aformentioned folder contains a thousand files and even more.

Answer (score 0):

Automator has that function built right in, via the **Set Spotlight Comments for Finder Items** Action:

[image]

You should be able to point the first action at your target folder, have it find all the files, and it will add the Comment to all of them.

Good luck,

Comment: Doesn't work. 2 error code results.
Can I send @Craig a screen shot pls?
How do I add that shot to this comment to reflect my response as above?

Comment: Request specification.

One folder contains 1.000 files. They all have different file names. Most have movie format extensions.
I want the script to target (one by one) those thousand names, copy (one by one) the original name and paste it (one by one) in the Spotlight Comment boxes of the OS X 10.8.5. files.
When done, the script should rename the original file name by putting the prefix DONE_ in front of that original name.

Comment: That is much more complex than I had originally believed.  From your original post, I believed that you were copying and pasting a single piece of data.  This sort of metadata massage is much more appropriate for AppleScript than Automator.   Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: No Craig. Sorry. Just a novice.
I want to attract movie footage from other people for a 'global meditation for peace' project.
Therefore I should be able to edit the file name myself based on my sorting criteria and put the title they used to describe their file to my downloaded file comment box.
As of yesterday, being a Belgian myself, my mission is more important than ever if you see what I mean.
In fact, I need a small army of coders to get my stuff done even faster now. It's all OS X Finder stuff related to creating fast sorting routines.

Comment: Don't know whether you know them but found two resources you may like:
http://www.amsys.co.uk/2013/02/how-to-append-the-spotlight-comments-on-files-without-going-into-get-info/
http://arstechnica.com/apple/2005/04/macosx-10-4/7/

So far, I didn't find a solution yet.